# Moving out of a function both owned and borrowed entities?

Tags: rust

What is proper way of doing that? What options are available? I am aware about the problem of dangled references and the problem of self-referential struct. Still I have strong intuition it's a reachable problem because both owner and borrowed reference are returned and no memory deallocation happen. Also it's quite general problem! In theory, it's a solvable one.

```rust
use byte_slice_cast::*;

fn main() {
    let context = context_make();
    dbg!(&context);
}

//

fn context_make<'a>() -> Context<'a> {
    Context::<'a>::new()
}

//

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Context<'a> {
    pub dst_buffer: Box<[f32]>,
    pub dst_buffer_bytes: &'a [u8],
}

//

impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    fn new() -> Context<'a> {
        let len: usize = 13;
        let dst_buffer: Box<[f32]> = vec![0_f32; len].into_boxed_slice();
        let dst_buffer_bytes = dst_buffer.as_byte_slice();
        Context {
            dst_buffer,
            dst_buffer_bytes,
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this code requires `byte-slice-cast = "1.2.0"`

Interesting to compare solutions if there are more than one alternatives.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af0b6da57a5d4153249f79f403d4d13e)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: That's definitely helpful, thanks. Still I believe my question add something. I have found solution with help of owning ref. I am looking for a solution with Pin and other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in safe rust. There are good reasons for this like not being able to trivially move the struct without changing where the reference points to.

Instead, you would implement a function to get that reference:

```rust
struct Context {
    pub dst_buffer: Box<[f32]>,
}

impl Context {
    fn new() -> Context {
        let len: usize = 13;

        Context {
            dst_buffer: vec![0_f32; len].into_boxed_slice(),
        }
    }

    fn dst_buffer_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        self.dst_buffer.as_byte_slice()
    }
}
```

And if you really want to print out the bytes too:

```rust
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Debug for Context {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("Context")
         .field("dst_buffer", &self.dst_buffer)
         .field("dst_buffer_bytes", self.dst_buffer_bytes())
         .finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: if you know that the `dst_buffer` is always 13 in length then you should instead use `[f32; 13]` that way you won't have to use the heap.

Comment: There is better solution without reducing the structure to single representation of the data. Interesting is it possible to reach the same result with help of `Pin`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kos there was a really nice article about just using pin for this on thisweekinrust: https://arunanshub.hashnode.dev/self-referential-structs-in-rust

Comment: Thank you. It's very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Solution I have found. It possible with help of create [`owning-ref`](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref). Interesting is it possible to reach the same result with help of standard Pin?

```
use byte_slice_cast::*;
use owning_ref::*;

fn main() {
    let context = Context::new();
    dbg!(&context);
    dbg!(context.dst.as_owner());
    dbg!(&*context.dst);
}

//

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Context {
    // pub dst_buffer : Box::< [ f32 ] >,
    // pub dst_buffer_bytes : &'a [ u8 ],
    pub dst: OwningRef<Box<[f32]>, [u8]>,
}

//

impl Context {
    fn new() -> Context {
        let len: usize = 2;
        let dst_buffer: Box<[f32]> = vec![0_f32; len].into_boxed_slice();
        // let dst_buffer_bytes = dst_buffer.as_byte_slice();

        let dst = OwningRef::new(dst_buffer);
        let dst = dst.map(|dst_buffer| dst_buffer.as_byte_slice());

        Context { dst }
        // Context { dst_buffer, dst_buffer_bytes }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7941b806b61c851a5a3f4d12de6f780a)

Comment: Yes, you can do safe self-referential structs with that crate or `ouroboros` but doing this should not be generally encouraged especially to new people learning rust. This is not what experienced rust programmers would do straight away.